# How to use/implement Mule in existing application to connect number of JMS connections?

Tags: jms, mule

Existing application already communicating with 3 JMS connections - 1 queue, 2 topics, might add few more JMS connections.

So at this point trying to understand, how mule is going to help in this scenario? Basically wanted to know how to start using mule (basic) in my existing application? Will Anypoint studio going to help in using Mule?
And do we have to keep Mule server running to start with it?

Comment: What's the nature of your existing application: web-app (WAR), standalone (JAR), other? Do you have routing/transformation needs on top of JMS integration?

Comment: It's a web application

Comment: Gonna consume messages from different connections and process them in my application. Initially it was only one JMS connection, but over the time it has increased to 2 more JMS connections. So wanted check if MULE is going to help or not..

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a matter of connecting to JMS, Mule won't make a big difference compared to using Spring JMS for example.

If you had complex transformation,routing or orchestration requirements, then Mule would definitely come handy.